Correct Application of Chain Rule?
\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dx} 4(2x + \sqrt{x^3+3})^{-2}\\\\
=\text{ }&4 \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (2x + \sqrt{x^3+3})^{-2}\\\\
=\text{ }&4\frac{-2}{(2x+\sqrt{x^3+3})^3} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(2x + \sqrt{x^3+3})\\\\
\end{align*}
This is as far as I could get before my solution deviated from the answer key I am using. How should I progress from here?

Continue using familiar rules of differentiation and find $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(2x+\sqrt{x^3+3}\right)$$

You are on the right track. Well done!
Based on your work, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
(2x + \sqrt{x^{3} + 3})' & = (2x)' + (\sqrt{x^{3} + 3})'\\\\
& = 2 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^{3} + 3}}\times(x^{3} + 3)'\\
& = 2 + \frac{3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{x^{3} + 3}}
\end{align*}

I believe you meant $x^3+3$ instead of $x^3+2$ starting from the second step onwards, but the method makes perfect sense. I came out with the solution $\frac{-8}{(2x+\sqrt{x^3+3})^3}\cdot(2+\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3+3}})$. Thank you so much!

@alpenglow Indeed. Thanks for pointing it out. I am glad to help.
